# Why isn't width and height of inner div's equal to outer div?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    .
    .
    .
    (900th div)
    <div></div>
  </div>
</html>


.grid{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}
.grid div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

I'm seeing 23 squares in a column instead of 30. I think all the 900 squares should fit into the grid class but they're overflowing. why are 23 squares in a single column and where are 140px(600-23*20) missing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your divs have borders. Using the default box sizing model, the border is not included into the width, so each div is actually wider than 20px. Either set [border box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to your div CSS:

```
.grid div{
  /* ... */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or make sure you are not forgetting the border; e.g.:

```
.grid div {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

(2 + 16 + 2 = 20)

Answer (score 0):

Because of borders! In my browser each has 3.333 px. If needed (almost always) use `box-sizing: border-box`, but even then a few pixels are always lost ...
And you wanted them separately - space counts too.
Actually, yours 900 `flex` squares would  probably trying to fit into smaller box; without begging, in a first  too small window;
This is why the `flex` is leaking so ugly - it tries no matter what